# How can I group worker requests by userId?

Tags: php, http, parallel-processing

I have a server which is constantly getting **a lot of requests every second**.
Some of them have similar parameter e.g. **userId**.

At this time I'm processing every request separatly (let's call an action for each request as **A**).

I would like that some **worker** perform only one action **A** for all requests with the same **userId**.

Example:

Unix time **100**

My server receives 10 requests with **userId = 1** and **userId = 2**, returns status Ok and passes requests to the worker which groups the requests by userId and produces the action **A**, first with data **userId = 1**, then **userId = 2** (order is not important).

So there are only **2** actions A **instead of 15**.

Then worker takes requests with unix time **101** groups them and performs action A ...

It is necessary that the time delay and resource costs are minimal.

I'm confused. How can I implement this?

Comment: It looks like you're looking for [queues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queueing_theory). Are you able to launch your worker automatically in order to read the queue and perform actions?

Comment: @A.L I've installed [php-amqp](https://github.com/pdezwart/php-amqp) but I don't know how to get all the queue messages to group them